# Component SelectOneMenu primefaces does not work on a Dialog component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

The `p:selectOneMenu` of PrimeFaces does not work within a `p:dialog`. His appearance is unconfigured. By removing the component, the others work correctly.

I have already `appendToBody="true"` in the dialog and it still does not work. If someone has already experienced this or has an idea of ​​this behavior, please leave your comment or response.

**Button that calls the dialog**

```
<button id="btnNovoContatoID" 
    class="btn btn-flat btn-info"
    onclick="PF('dlgNovoContato').show(); return false;"
    jsf:update="modalNovoContato"
    >Novo Contato
</button>
```

**Include Dialog**

```
<ui:define name="popups">
    <ui:include src="teste.xhtml"/>
</ui:define>
```

**Complete form**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:sgr="http://www.sgr.com.br/jsf"  
                template="/WEB-INF/facelets/templates/layout.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="form_id" value="formCadPessoa"/>
    <ui:param name="titlePage" value="Pessoa"/>
    <ui:param name="subTitlePage" value="Cadastrado de Pessoas"/>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{pessoaBean.inicializarFormParaEdicao(param.pessoaId)}"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:define name="panelCadastro">

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-7" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
            <p:outputLabel value="Nome:"/>
            <p:inputText id="inptNome" value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.nome}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-3" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo Pessoa:"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="iptTipPessoa" value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.tipoPessoa}" converter="tipoPessoaConverter" >
                <p:ajax event="change" update="lblCpf"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{pessoaBean.tiposPessoa}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel id="lblCpf" value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.tipoPessoa eq 'FISICA' ? 'CPF' : 'CNPJ'}:"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.cpfCnpj}" maxlength="14"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Nascimento:"/>
            <p:calendar value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.dataNascimento}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-12" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
            <div class="box-title pull-right">
                <button id="btnNovoContatoID" 
                        class="btn btn-flat btn-info"
                        onclick="PF('dlgNovoContato').show(); return false;"
                        jsf:update="modalNovoContato"
                        >Novo Contato
                </button>
            </div>
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:dataTable id="dtContatos" var="obj" value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.contatos}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                Contatos Cadastrados
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Tipo" width="20%">
                <h:outputText value="#{obj.tipoContato}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Descrição" width="80%">
                <h:outputText value="#{obj.descricao}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="footerBoxButton">
        <button id="btnSalvarID"
                type="submit" 
                jsf:update="messages,formCadPessoa"
                jsf:process="@form"
                class="btn btn-flat btn-success"
                jsf:action="#{pessoaBean.salvar}">Salvar
        </button>

        <p:spacer width="10"/>

        <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn  btn-default">Voltar</a>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="popups">
        <ui:include src="teste.xhtml"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Dialog Page**

```
<p:dialog xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:sgr="http://www.sgr.com.br/jsf"   
    id="modalNovoContato"
    header="Novo Contato" 
    widgetVar="dlgNovoContato" 
    minHeight="200"
    width="650"
    resizable="false" 
    closeOnEscape="true">

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-9" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
        <h:outputLabel value="Tipo Contato:" />

        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{pessoaBean.contato.tipoContato}" converter="tipoContatoConverter" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{pessoaBean.tiposContato}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputLabel value="Descrição:"/>
        <p:inputText label="inputDescricao" style="width: 300px">
            <sgr:upperCase/>
        </p:inputText>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <button id="btnSalvarContatoID" 
            type="submit" 
            jsf:update="messages"
            jsf:process="@form"
            jsf:action="#{pessoaBean.salvar}"
            class="btn btn-flat btn-success">Adicionar
        </button>
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

**Wrong dialog image**

[image]

Comment: Friend, if you do not have any comments or answers to the question, please do not pollute the subject, leave it to those who actually contribute. If you pay close attention to the issue along with the codes and images, you will understand very well the term does not work, that I really do not see another term to be referring to the problem

Comment: I was not offended, I was just surprised by your reaction which indicates to me you don't want any real help... Since your question **is** unclear, your code **does** contain way to much noise and ** cannot** be copy/pasted in a clean jsf project. All of which you'd see if you carefully read about [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and http://sscce.org/ ... Cheers (removed my other comments since to keep your question 'clean')